# Snowflake SQL 'group by' with Range (1:n)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregation, datagrip, group

In Snowflake SQL, I want to write group by statement dynamically.

Actual: `group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

Requires: `group by 1:10`

Is this thing possible?

By the way, I am using DataGrip.
It has Live Templates, but Live Templates abbreviations are not dynamic.

For example, I write `grbyn`, n is variable, and template generates `group by 1, 2, 3, ..., n`.

`grby4` --> `group by 1, 2, 3, 4`

`grby7` --> `group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

If anyone who using Datagrip, also there are an option like that.

Comment: No - this is not possible

Comment: Thanks for reply NickW. 
If anyone can help with DataGrip Live Template, I would be glad that.

Comment: You can create a new template and try something like:
`group by ${start:int}${COLS:colRanges(start, end)}${end:int}`

Comment: Hi Aleix CC. In here, how can I enter the `n` variable at the template?  For example `grby4`. In this example, default starting value will be 1 and end value will be 4.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact situation, you could consider modifying the field values to a common level and then grouping on the value (all in the group by).

You could play around truncating/rounding/flooring and so on:
Some examples:

1. `TRUNCATE(7,-1) = 0`
2. `TRUNCATE(9,-1) = 0`

For 10 though, that would truncate to 10, so it really comes down to your particular scenario.